# Expected Value of a transformation of a random variable

Tags: expected-value

Suppose there is a random variable $X$
  which is defined as follows:$$X=k\times log(Y)$$
  where Y
  is distributed uniformly on the $[0,1]$
  interval and $k$
  is a negative real number. I want to calculate the mean of X.
  I take expectations on both sides:$$E[X]=E[klog(Y)]$$
 $$=kE[log(Y)]$$
 $$=k[\int_{0}^{1}log(y)f(y)dy]$$
 and using the fact that $f(y)=1$
 , we obtain the definite integral:$$=k[xlog(x)-x\}_{0}^{1}]$$
  which does not exist because $log(0)$
  is undefined. How do I procoeed?

Comment: The right hand side, by definition, is $k(1\log(1) - 1) - \lim_{x\to 0^{+}} k(x\log(x) - x)$, and that limit *is* defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \ x \log(x) = 0 $$

it is convention to define $0 \times \log(0) = 0$. Therefore, the integral equals $-k$.